# L'orientation des accents est-elle liée à l'intonation ?

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, intonation

Something I noticed while reading words with diacritical marks is that the direction of the of mark (either acute or grave) produces a stressed sound that coincides with the direction of the mark — or at least I think.

So I would like to ask, when pronouncing, for example, *á* and *à*, would one produce a sound with rising and falling intonation, respectively?

---

Lorsqu'on lit des mots avec des diacritiques, est-ce que l'orientation du signe (soit aigu ou soit grave) indique le sens de l'intonation ?

Quand on est en train de prononcer *á* et *à*, produit-on un son avec une intonation montante et descendante, respectivement ?

Answer (score 8):

As a matter of fact, the letter "á" is not used in French. Diacritics only affect the quality of the vowel -- that is, the "place" in the mouth where the sound is formed -- not intonation, tone, stress or anything like that. (In certain dialects, diacritics may also indicate the *duration* of a vowel.)

The letters with diacritics that change the vowel sound in French are è é ê ô and for some speakers â.

#### Accents on E

An accent mark on E indicates that it is not pronounced as schwa (ə), but as a front unrounded vowel of some kind (that is, a vowel in the area of IPA [e] or [ɛ]). The exact number and distribution of non-schwa E sounds varies between dialects/accents of French.

- É usually corresponds to the sound /e/, called "close e". This sound doesn't exist in English, but it's like an /ɛ/ that is pronounced with the tongue slightly higher in the mouth. Some people find it helpful to think of it as the sound in "grey", but with the y-like sound at the end removed or smoothed out. It is a pure vowel sound, unlike the "ay" sound in English. I said "usually" because the phenomenon of "vowel height harmony" causes some speakers to use [ɛ] instead in some words where a low vowel is in the following syllable. See [Eau qui dort's comment here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22068/pronunciation-of-the-%C3%A9-in-m%C3%A9decin?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment42750_22075) for an explanation of this.
- È is pronounced basically like the vowel sound in English "bet", called "open e", and transcribed /ɛ/ in the International Phonetic Alphabet. I can't think of any exceptions to this. In some accents, it apparently may represent a long open front vowel, /ɛː/, in certain words (see the next bullet for more discussion of this; I first learned about it from James's question [Pronunciation of “freiner”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/pronunciation-of-freiner)).
- Ê is typically also pronounced as an open e. The digraph aî makes the same sound. In some accents, the letter Ê represents a distinctively long vowel /ɛː/, but  I believe this distinction is lost for many speakers nowadays. I was never taught to do so, but as an example, some people pronounce "maître" with a longer vowel sound than "mettre". As with É, "vowel harmony" effects cause Ê to have a different pronunciation for some speakers in certain words where it is not in the last syllable: for example, the word "bêtise" can be pronounced with a close e in the first syllable (/betiz(ə)/) because of the high vowel /i/ in the last syllable.

#### The circumflex accent on O or A

- The vowel ô is pronounced like the digraph "au": a close o sound, IPA /o/, that has no exact English counterpart. (For American English speakers, it is a bit like the "oh" sound smoothed out to make it a pure vowel sound. For British English speakers, the vowel sound of "aw", as in the word "law", may have a similar quality, as aCOSwt pointed out in a comment.) In accents with vowel length, this is a long vowel.
- The letter â can be pronounced on various ways: in Parisian French, the tendency is to pronounce it the same as an unaccented letter a, with a sound a bit like that in the English word "cat". In more conservative varieties of the language, it has a sound like the sound in English "father". It is also a long vowel in accents with vowel length.

#### Other accents don't affect pronunciation as a rule

A circumflex accent can also appear on the letters î and û, but it is not generally associated with a different pronunciation. Some speakers have a different pronunciation for the digraph eû compared to the digraph eu; as far as I know the only words where these contrast are *jeune* /ʒœn/ and *jeûne* /ʒø:n/ or /ʒøn/ or even /ʒœ:n/. But this distinction is not universal even among French speakers.

The letters à and ù have the same pronunciation as the unaccented letters, but they are used in the spelling of some common words to differentiate homophones. The most common example is the preposition spelled *à* vs. the form of the verb avoir spelled *a*. (The only word spelled with 'ù' is the word *où* 'where', to distinguish it from *ou* 'or'.)

You might also see the trema mark, two dots above a vowel, that shows that the vowel must be pronounced separately from a preceding vowel. For example, the word naïve has two syllables, so it gets a trema on the ï.

Comment: _The letter à is not pronounced any differently from an unaccented a, it's just a different way of spelling the same sound._ Just to correct, Yes is it the same sound, but no, it's not a different way of spelling. `à` will never be in a word (but là), it is an adverbial used for `to/from/at/...`. While `a` alone is the verb `to have`.

Comment: You can also have `ù` but like `à` it's the same sound as it letters without accent. `à` and `ù` exist because we need to make the distinction between two words which are said and wrote the same. Like `où` is where and `ou` is or.

Comment: And about `^`, it's a bit more tricky, there is actually no rules for this accent. You can use it on all vowel but y, so you will find `â/ê/î/ô/û`. Most of the time, it sounds the same. But there is some exception. Like `jeûne` where the `û` will be silent, while in `jeune` you have to pronounce it.

Comment: The only point I will disagree is with the ô, which you correctly say equivalent to "au" but surprisingly associate it with "oh". ô does get some english counterpart which is "aw" like in "*law*". ô frequently appears in french words borrowed from ancient greek standing for the omega which o is, in english, pronounced "aw" as in law. Thanks for your fantastic contribution anyway.

Comment: @aCOSwt: Ah, that depends on one's accent of English. In many varieties of British English, "aw" as in "law" is indeed something like [oː], very similar to French  ô. But I'm an American English speaker, and for me "aw" is [ɑː]: not at all similar! My "oh" is [oʊ], so it is closer. I know British speakers tend to use a value more like [əʊ] for "oh".