# Pronunciation of “freiner”

Tags: prononciation, québec, voyelles

In Quebec French, is the [ɛ] long or short in the word *(il) freine*? In other words, does this word rhyme with *saine* [sɛn] or *scène* [sɛ:n]?

(And out of curiosity, how would those few French people who still make this distinction answer the question? The answer to this kind of question isn't always the same in France and in Quebec, it seems.)

Comment: Does *scène* have a long vowel? What is the origin of this distinction? I knew that there were dialects with a long vowel in circumflexed words, like *maître*, and that there is a phonetically long vowel in most French dialects before the "r" "rv" "z" and "j" sounds, but not that there are ones with a long vowel in *scène*.

Comment: The distinction disappeared from Parisian French only recently. The Littré dictionary shows the distinction, and if memory serves, so did editions of Le Robert in the 1960s. However, it is likely that by the 1960s, only a small minority of speakers in Paris observed it. I've met an older speaker from Normandy who maintained it, as well as a younger one from Vendée. Spelling is not a fully reliable guide - for example, *l'aide* has a long vowel and *laide* a short one.

Comment: Some info: of course that [wiki](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois); also [topo](http://phono.uqac.ca/), [articles](http://www.erudit.org/revue/cl/1974/v/n4/) and [audio](http://www.phonetique.ulaval.ca/exerque.html).

Comment: @sumelic In case you never found a satisfactory answer in the last 4 years, I suspect the long vowel of scène was used to used to represent the diphthong of scænam when the word was borrowed in the 16th C. Long vowels in learned borrowings of that period are frequent and occasionally overapplied (as in trône, atone).

Answer (score 2):

I use a short [-ɛn] in all of *freine*, *saine* and *scène* (Southern French).

Answer (score 2):

Pour répondre directement à la question, *Freine* rime avec *scène* en français québécois (mais pas avec *saine*). Je ne crois pas que l'orthographe "ai" serve jamais à transcrire [ɛ:], du moins, aucun mot ne me viens à l'esprit vite comme ça (quoique ce soit parfois le cas de "aî", comme dans *maître* et *faîte*).

Comment: J'essaye de comprendre tout ça : le "e" fermé latin de _frenum_ a la marque du e fermé tonique. LBU par. 60 dit que ça devient "ei", puis "we"(roe vs. rwa), puis se réduit dans certains cas à  [ɛ]: _habebat, aveit, avoit, avait_. Ensuite au par. 66 on analyse l'influence de la nasalisation et si la consonne se prononce, alors la voyelle tonique subsiste et devient ouverte: plena(m) - pleine. Si la consonne est finale, elle se combine à la voyelle et se nasalise: plenu(m) - plein avec [ɛ̃]. Ensuite je vois la note au bas [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2137) ??

Comment: Je ne connais pas les détails de l'origine phonétique de ce son (qui n'a d'ailleurs pas tout à fait, du moins à mes oreilles, la valeur phonétique de /ɛ/). Toutefois, je crois savoir à quelles variations phonétiques cette note de l'OQLF fait référence sans avoir à télécharger la police en question: en québécois, /ɑ̃/ ("an") est plutôt prononcé /ã/ tandis que /ɛ̃/ ("in") est généralement prononcé /ẽ/.

Answer (score 1):

For me (Belgian), it is a long one.