# Comment prononcer 'ai' dans "epaissir", "laisser" etc

Tags: prononciation

Je suis au courant du fait qu'on peux prononcer `ai` comme soit `é` soit `è`.

Mais je viens de remarquer que mon dictionnaire dit qu'on peut également prononcer un `ai` comme `é` dans d'autres cas, par example dans les mots `épaissir` (épésir) et `laisser` (lésé).

Quand je fais des cherches sur Google il me semble que qu'il n'existe que des discussions sur les terminaisons. Alors, quelles sont les règles de grammaires dans ce cas?

Merci!

---

I know that you can pronounce verb endings of `-ai` as either `é` or `è`.

But I've noticed that my Swedish-French Dictionary (who is on team `é`) suggests that you should also pronounce `ai` as `é` in some other situations, such as in the words `épaissir` (épésir) and `laisser` (lésé).

I seem to only find discussions on the former case, so what are the rules in my case?

Look forward to hear your thoughts (altough I guess it's dialectal in this case too)!

Merci!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not an expert or a native speaker, but here is my understanding.

The phonemic contrast in French between /e/ (as in *né*) and /ɛ/ (as in *lait, muet, muette*) is fairly variable and unclear in non-final syllables.

In fact, even « é » in a non-final syllable is not always pronounced as /e/; some speakers pronounce « é » as /ɛ/ in some contexts. (In reformed spelling, some but not all words have spelling variants with « è » to reflect this, like *évènement* in place of the traditional spelling *événement*).

Two factors that can influence the pronunciation of « ai », « é » and « ê » in non-final syllables are syllable structure and vowel harmony.

In *épaissir* and *laisser,* the vowel in the syllable following « ai » is close or mid-close. This influences some speakers to pronounce the « ai » as mid-close [e] rather than as mid-open [ɛ]. Similarly, « ê » can be pronounced [e] in certain words, like *[bêtise](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/betise),* even though « ê » in the final syllable of a word usually corresponds only to [ɛ].

Likewise, there are speakers who pronounce *[aimer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23327/questions-sociolinguistiques-sur-la-prononciation-de-aimer)* as [eme], but *aimable* as [ɛmabl], because in *aimer* the vowel in the following syllable is mid-close [e] but in *aimable* the vowel in the following syllable is open [a]. But as far as I know, all speakers pronounce *aime* as [ɛm(ə)]; likewise, all speakers would I think use [ɛ] in the last syllable of *épaisse.* (With *épais,* the situation gets a bit more complicated: /ɛ/ in the last syllable is definitely standard, but because the vowel comes at the end of the word in an "open" syllable (with no consonant sound following it), speakers in a few regions may tend to pronounce the vowel in a way that sounds more like [e].)

The user Eau qui dort left a comment beneath another one of my posts that talks about this: [Pronunciation of the « é » in « médecin »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22068/pronunciation-of-the-%C3%A9-in-m%C3%A9decin/22075#comment42750_22075)

I don't think the use of [e] vs. [ɛ] in contexts like *épaissir* and  *laisser* is a big deal. There are regional variations, but as far as I know it is not a major marker of a regional accent.

Comment: Ah, I see, this makes sense! I sometimes struggle with keeping the two different e sounds seperated when one follows the other quickly. In the example words it comes much more natural to me to say 'épéssir', so I guess I'll stick with that.Hopefully some native speakers will chip in on the discussion.

Comment: Well, I never ever heard that ai and é can be pronounced the same way.  Of course, when speaking things do happen. That said, what is pronouncing the verb ai as  è?? There is only /e/ (as in né) and /ɛ/, Il est allé, /e/ versus Il allait are not the same.....

Comment: @Lambie: well, I was only talking about non-final syllables, so “ai”, “allait” and “allé” are not included

Comment: @Mumfi My comment was directed more to the OP. Anyway, there is no such thing as a final è, wouldn't you agree?? The verb ending can only be: é /e/ or /ɛ/. But I would argue that épaissir is  never: épéssir......It's hard sometimes to hear it. It took me a long time, in my teens.

Comment: @Lambie: I think the OP is just using "è" to mean /ɛ/. I'm surre many people use /ɛ/ in the second syllable of "épaissir", and I would guess some people might use some kind of intermediate value. But, it seems plausible to me based on what I've read that at least some people might just use /e/.

Comment: @sumelic No worries. Though I am taking the épaissir thing with a huge grain of sea salt. :)

Comment: @Lambie When I wrote about verbs ending with è and é I actually meant    /ɛ/ and /e/. I was too lazy to use the correct phonetic notations, sorry for the confusion. 

From my brief research it seems like people would pronounce épaissir as [epesir] in the southern parts of France. On forvo.com my ears seem to pick up either [lɛsɛ]/[ɛpɛsir]. Few people seem to use both sounds in this case. For laisser, it's either with ɛ or e in the first sound.

Comment: It's supposed to say [epesir]/[ɛpɛsir].

Answer (score 2):

As a french speaker, my knee-jerk reaction would have been to say */ɛ/* in all cases. That is how I hear the words in my head while reading them, and how I learned their pronunciation in my youth.

However, I tried pronouncing them out loud, and it seems that I would say "épéssir" and "lésser" when in the context of a full sentence. On their own, I'd pronounce them "lèsser" and "épèssir".

In any case, what I learned when I was younger is that *-ai* was **always** pronounced */ɛ/*.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any real consensus, so I guess it's up to the speaker to choose. I find it quite unnatural to throw in an "épèssir" in a sentence, so i'll probably stick to what my dictionary told me and which sparked the question, i.e. "épéssir"

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, epaissir et laisser, it all depends and both are correct
i would say épéssir and lésser and also épèssie et lèsser or émmer or émmer.

when you speak you tend not to focus to much on certain sounds, it could be a sound between  é and é, it is quite subtle